# php socket.io with symfony

Tags: php, ios, symfony, sockets

I have a symfony project where I want to use websockets.
This is actually a project to provide mobile application with apis. From mobile(IOS,Android) there must be request with post data to server(for example /mobile/ => goes to symfony ClientController -> indexAction) where I need to run the socket, open channel and send message, and on mobile application will also used socket.io to detect messages from socket channel.

> Is there a way to use socket.io in symfony?

I have installed Ratchet it seams working ok, but in all examples I found connection and message sending was done with client side, with JS,

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

> I don't need client side, It is planning that server will run the
>   socket, open new channel and send message through it. Something like
>   it is done with nodeJS and socket.io (using - broadcast, emit, on,
>   functions)

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php ?

Answer (score -1):

The best tool for the job seems to be this bundle: https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle. You probably need a PHP Websocket server that you start and configure with the above bundle.

If I understood correctly, the mobile applications (iOS, Android) will be the clients.

Comment: very poor document and too complicated for customization